# CSS and Fonts Render Differently on Web Server Compared to Development Environment

Tags: html, css, asp.net, deployment

I have a .NET Core 2.2 MVC application that I'm developing. My website looks perfect when I run it locally in chrome, however when I deploy to Azure App Service (also ran in chrome), the fonts are different, and some of the CSS styling is too.

There are no resource 404's when I check the developer console locally, and I have examined the file structure of wwwroot, comparing both live and local and they both appear to be the same.

What could be causing this? I have attached two comparison pictures below, thank you in advance.

[Local view (correct)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gpCC.png)

[Live view (incorrect)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XERS0.png)

Comment: do you reload page without cache?

Comment: @HansFelixRamos Thanks for the response, I've tried this and it made no difference